# InterlockedPushListSList is missing. Where is it?

Tags: winapi, synchronization, compiler-errors

I am developing on a Windows Server 2008 box, with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, SP1. Unfortunately, the function [`InterlockedPushListSList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448545%28v=vs.10%29.aspx) is causing errors because it is undefined in my copy of `WinBase.h`.

Declaring the function myself does not work; linker errors occur. It looks like this function is not defined in the windows libraries for my compiler. But the documentation linked to above states that it is available for my operating system.

Some Googling has revealed that the API has been around since the development of Windows Longhorn, albeit from a non-official [source](http://mikedimmick.blogspot.com.au/2004/07/changes-to-win32-api-in-longhorn_21.html), so there shouldn't be any reason for it to be missing from my point of view.

Does this function *actually* exist? If so, where can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem with MSVC 2010 and Windows SDK v7.0A. `InterlockedPushListSList` is not present in WinBase.h. When declaring it, I first also got a linking error... until I realized I forgot the `extern "C"` :-). Maybe you also forgot that? I could compile and link if I declared

```
extern "C"
PSLIST_ENTRY  FASTCALL InterlockedPushListSList(
  _Inout_  PSLIST_HEADER ListHead,
  _Inout_  PSLIST_ENTRY List,
  _Inout_  PSLIST_ENTRY ListEnd,
  _In_     ULONG Count
);
```

Comment: Wow... so simple. I'll try it out and let you know if it works.

Comment: Please note: This function doesn't seem to be available for 32-bit projects.

Comment: What do you mean with "not available"? Not in the Header file (-> Compiler error) or not in the library (-> linker error)? I compiled and linked for Win32 (which is Default in MSVC 2010).

Comment: Hmmm, curious. I received linker errors for `InterlockedPushListSList` under Win32, but linked fine under x86-64.